# Comparing lines, -notcontains gets ignored

Tags: string, powershell

I want to parse a .dat file with plain text (strings and values) in it.

For example, I want the Value behind "NAME:". But there also is a line with "FAM.NAME:" in it.

But I only want the one with NAME.
This is what I tried:

```
$content= Get-Content $_.FullName
foreach($line in $content){  
   if($line -contains "NAME" -and $line -notcontains "FAM" ) { $test= $line  }
}
```

As far as I understand, the condition is that the line contains "NAME"   AND does NOT contain "FAM".

The Output is "FAM.NAME: ALFREDO". It seems to ignore the condition after the -and. Why is that?

Comment: `-contains` and `-notcontains` works on a collection list, not on string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `-match` and `-notmatch` to compare strings, instead of `-contains` and `-notcontains` which operate on arrays.

```
$content= Get-Content $_.FullName
foreach($line in $content){  
   if($line -match "NAME" -and $line -notmatch"FAM" ) { $test= $line  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can also use the `-like` operator -

```
PS>"FAM.NAME: ALFREDO" -like "NAME*"  
False             

PS>"NAME: ALFREDO" -like "NAME*"  
True
```

Note - make sure to add the `*` to match the rest of the string, otherwise it won't match